# C++ / How does a iterator work for a Set of class object?

Tags: c++, pointers, set

I've been teaching myself C++, and found an interesting thing.

According to [this web page,](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/):

> The most obvious form of iterator is a pointer.

So, I used to think that an iterator object works in almost the same way as a pointer (e.g. `int *i`);

However, now I guess that it would be more accurate to say an iterator object is like a pointer of a pointer (such as `int **i`) rather than a pointer (`int *i`).

I noticed this, when I was coding the following one.

```
set<Point*, Point> points; //This class encapsulates x and y coordinates for a 2 dimensional point
set<Point*, Point>::iterator it;

int x = 22;
int y = 4;
Point* pt = new Point(x, y);
points.insert(pt);
//Similar statements are here, to insert other Point objects with different arguments

for (it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); it++) {
    cout << "**it: " << **it << ", *it :" << *it << ", Address : " << &it << endl;
}
```

As a result,

1. `**it` showed values of Pointer class objects
2. `*it` showed addresses
3. `&it` showed the address of the `it` object

[image]

So, is it right to say that an iterator object (`it`) is basically the same as `**it`?

Another question which is a bit different from iterators:

If I need to make a set of class object, like: `set<ClassName*, ClassName> SetName;`, what would be the correct way? (as long as this class contains comparable data type, like `int` or `double`)

I'd appreciate if you'd give some advice.

Comment: _`set<Point*, Point> points;`_ This looks very strange. The second template type parameter of [`std::set<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is meant to be a Compare operation used to sort the contained items. How did you declare `Point` to provide the pointer comparison?

Comment: Hint: what is your set storing? Pointers? Or something else? If you stored `Point**` in the set, would you conclude that an iterator is more like `int***`?

Comment: The only reason you need a double pointer is because you're storing a pointer type in your set.

Comment: Also double pointer is required only if you want to change the address of the pointed object. Similary with pointer you can modify the value of the object which is pointed out by the pointer. Its better to assume it is closer to pointer . As the requirement of the iterator is to iterate the elements and modify the values of the element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a wrong assumption. In your example the `value_type` of the set is pointer `Point *`. And `*it` gives you an element in the set that is a reference to some object of this `value_type` that is of type `Point *` and `++it` "points" to the next element in the set. So the iterator behaves the same way as pointer to an object of `value_type`.

When you use expression like `**it` then the second dereference is not applied to the iterator. It is applied to an object in the set. You can imagine expression `**it` the following way

```
Point *pp = *it;

Point p = *pp;
```

Iterator of a container is responsible to provide you access to elements of the container. Thus if elements in the container has type `value_type` then the iterator provides access to these elements of this value_type. The elements in turn can be pointers to objects or even pointers to pointers to objects and so on.

As for your second question then if the class has the corresponding operator function and the class itself has some simple default constructor then you may use such an approach though it would be better to define a separatw comparator or simply to define `operator <` for objects of the class. In the last case you can write

```
std::set<Point> s;
```

without explicit second template argument.

Here is demonstrative program of your approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>



int main() 
{
    struct Point
    {
        int x, y;
        bool operator ()( const Point &p1, const Point &p2 ) const
        {
            return p1.x < p2.x && p1.y < p2.y;
        }
    };

    std::set<Point, Point> s;
    s.insert( { 2, 2 } );
    s.insert( { 1, 1 } );

    for ( const Point &p : s ) std::cout << p.x << ' ' << p.y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 1
2 2
```